# SAP Web IDE Authorization

Tags: sap-web-ide

I was wondering if it is possible to authenticate in the SAP Web IDE. I am using a Java back end which authorizes users depending on their role. The authorization works just fine when I register the app the a portal site (launchpad). Is there a way I can authorize in the IDE aswell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just set permission for WebIDE to everyone. it should redirect you to your own login page/IDP upon trying to open it.